# Run Php script without browser

Tags: php, ajax

I have a file (given by a user through a form) that takes about 30 mins to import, what I want to do is as soon as the user submit the file I want to display a message saying that they'll receive an email once the import is done. My problem is that I want to display that message and process the file without the browser (i,e I dont want the browser to wait until the import is finished). How can I achieve this? I looked at `ignore_user_abort(true)/set_time_limit(0)` but I saw my page loading (and waiting for the response from the server)

Comment: 1. take a look at the command line versions of the php engine, 2. learn how to use a cron daemon and 3. stop doing all of this due to _massive_ security issues this raises.

Comment: Executing a client side provided script on your system is like handing out your root password to anyone asking for it.

Comment: This is for a client and I can't really do much since it's a requirement

Comment: Then 1. tell the client what the issue is and if the client still insists then 2. tell the client that you, as a responsible thinking professional, will certainly _not_ implement something that obviously is harmful.

Comment: Don't get this wrong, but I am always flabbergasted how people sell their skills (that is what I understand by the term "client") whilst apparently being absolute greenhorns in their field. And then will wipe aside serious and helpful warnings by mentioning that they "have to" do that, that it is "not their decision" and that they "know all this" and would "never do that myself"...

Comment: Well I understand your point. How can I do this then since the client wants a UI so that they can do their own import?

Comment: "... And then will wipe aside ..." q.e.d.

Comment: Using some virtual machine to execute the unknown code on might be an approach, or easier a docker container. That way you can separate the performing host system from the (potentially malicious) unknown code you have to execute.

Comment: It might be easier to give helpful assistance if you would provide some insight into what kind if "import" that is meant to be and why that has to be done by means of scripts that have to be executed. That is a _very_ uncommon approach, that is why I ask.